# What base theme can i can use in component based theme in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Which is best base theme is suitable for component based theme  in drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start with `classy` theme, which provides some minimal scaffolding and is somewhat component-based, depending on your definition.